# tap event: how to set an event for first tap, and another event for second tap

Tags: windows-phone-8, tap

I'm developing a Windows phone 8 app with visual studio.

I made two buttons, `button1` and `button2`, and two textblocks that are under each button.

`Button2` is under the `button1`, so `button2` and `textblock1` are overlaying each other.

When user clicks `button1` I set `textblock1.Visibility` = true, and change `button2`'s margin, so the app renders the following layout:

In the upper part there is the `button1`.

The `textblock1` is in the middle

And  the `button2` is in the lowest part.

Now, when I re-tap the `button1` I just want that `textblock1.Visibility` turns false and `button2` returns to is original position. So I want to implement a species of dropdown button text, but i haven't find a way to do that.

Can anyone help me? Is there another way to to that?

I've tried a `Listpicker` from WPToolkit, but I don't want the selected item to be shown in the listpicker when this is not selected, and substantially I have the same tap problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer to the question that is in your thread title : "tap event: how to set an event for first tap, and another event for second tap".

There is several ways, you can set up a boolean variable or increase a counter.

In your case, you can check the visibility of your `textblock1` :

```
if(textblock1.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
{
    //first click
    textblock1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
else {
    //second click
    textblock1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

To the previous code you just have to add your instructions for the `button2` position.

If you want to create your own `ListPicker` or `ComboBox`, you can read [this tutorial](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/recreons-la-combobox-pour-windows-phone) but it is in french... :)

Comment: So many thanks!! Now I think it's very easy to do, It's my first app! I'm a donk!